# How to change instance region in Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I tried to run DataflowJavaSDK WordCount example in my gcp project,
But the message show:

Workflow failed. Causes: (638fd23bd03812d4): Internal error: workflow failed. Please contact dataflow-feedback@google.com. Causes: (e52def24e835d7ad): Insufficient quota(s) to execute workflow for project my-project in the region us-central1, 3 instance(s) require 12 CPUs, 3000 disk GB, 0 SSD disk GB, 3 in-use IP addresses, available 9 CPUs, 2770 disk GB, 1024 SSD disk GB, 12 in-use IP addresses.

I want to change us-central1 to europe-west1, because there has enough quota that I can run example.

It's posible to change region?

(Sorry about my poor english...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the zone by a command line flag, for example, `--zone=europe-west1-b`.